# Why does window function return incorrect result in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table as blow, and want to write a query to return the earliest event_date for each player.

```
+--------------+---------+
| Column Name  | Type    | 
+--------------+---------+
| player_id    | int     |
| event_date   | date    |
+--------------+---------+
```

A query like below definitely works:

```
select player_id,
       min(event_date)  as first_login
from activity
group by player_id;
```

I am wondering why a query that uses window function does not also give the correct answer. Any insights on this?

```
  select player_id,
         min(event_date) over (partition by player_id) as first_login
  from activity
  group by player_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are using MariaDB, because in MySql 8.0+ your 2nd query would not even run.
If you run just:

```
select player_id, event_date
from activity
group by player_id;
```

although the query logically does not make sense and would fail in most databases, MariaDB allows it and returns an undefined value for `event_date`, which could be the value of the *first* row of each `player_id`.
If you then apply `MIN()` window function:

```
min(event_date) over (partition by player_id)
```

`MIN()` has only that value of `event_date` to operate and this is what you get.

Window functions are not supposed to replace the usual aggregate functions when used in a statement with a `GROUP BY` clause.
In such a case they could only operate on the results of the aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

The query is malformed and should return an error, because `event_date` is not surrounded by aggregation function or in the `group by`.

I'm not sure what you want.  The equivalent of the `group by` is:

```
select distinct player_id,
        min(event_date) over (partition by player_id) as first_login
from activity;
```

If you want the aggregation, though, use the aggregation query.

If you want to use window functions along with aggregation, here is an example query:

```
select player_id,
       min(event_date)  as first_login,
       min(min(event_date)) as first_ever_login
from activity
group by player_id;
```

Note that the aggregation function is nested in the window function.